# No me ejecuta el programa deseado

Tags: java

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado ejecutar este programa y no se por que no me ejecuta. Me gustaria que alguien me dijiera a que se debe este error... 
Lo intente con otra pc y cuando ejecute el programa decia que " No se puede lanzar este programa por que no hay lanzamientos disponibles " Le agradeceria al que me respondiera por favor. Gracias.
Estoy trabajando con Eclipse.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad, cualquier trozo de código que se anexe a las preguntas debe ser en forma de texto y no en imagen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/**
 * @author dejuanfran
 *
 */
public class Empleado {

    public static double salario;
    public static String nombre= "Alex";

    public Empleado() {

    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Empleado.salario=1000;
        System.out.println("El empleado "+Empleado.nombre+ " tiene un salario de "+Empleado.salario);
    }

}
```

Este código funciona perfectamente creo que es lo que necesitabas , te recomiendo que empieces a crear los atributos de los objetos privados y hagas uso de los getters y setters.

Creo que tu error estaba en que el main lo tenias dentro de una clase EmpDemo pero no te lo puedo decir con seguridad.

Espero que te haya servido.